# Calling javascript function with 'arguments' using received 'arguments' issue

Tags: javascript, arguments

My issue is best illustrated with a small code example available on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f96J8/):

```
function a() {
    alert("a: " + arguments.length);
    b(arguments);
}

function b() {
    alert("b: " + arguments.length);
}

a(33,445,67);
```

I have a function `a` called with a variable number of arguments, and I would like to call `b` with these arguments. Unfortunately, when I run the code above, it displays respectively 3 and 1, rather than 3 and 3.

How can I call `b` with all the arguments received in `a`?

Comment: You already call b with all the arguments, but like adeneo said, you call it with the argument-Object [33,445,67], this means your argument-Object in b looks like this [[33,445,67]].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is an array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function, so when `b()` is called there is only one argument, the array.
You can use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which accepts the arguments as an array instead

```
function a() {
    alert("a: " + arguments.length);
    b.apply(undefined, arguments);
}

function b() {
    alert("b: " + arguments.length);
}

a(33,445,67);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nUxr2/2/)

Comment: Actually b.apply(null, arguments); or a relevant first argument will return the desired result.

Comment: @Arbel - Why would null be more relevant than `this` when both functions are in the same parent scope ?

Comment: @adeneo: *"Why would null be more relevant than this when both functions are in the same parent scope ?"* Scope and `this` have almost nothing to do with one another, in JavaScript. `this` is (until ES6's arrow functions) set primarily by how a function is called, not where it's defined.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - That's true, but in this case the functions are both defined in the same scope, and a() is called from that scope, so `this` would have the correct value, but as it's not used anyway it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @adeneo: Right. But again, I would really stay away from combining "scope" and "`this`" when talking about JavaScript, as they really are unrelated, and the fact they're unrelated but people tend to think they're related is one of the biggest problems people have with JS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I agree, and we see it all the time right here on SO when someone new with javascript starts messing around with objects and dot notation and can't understand why `this` changes, but this is pretty clearcut, and even if I used `Infinity` or `NaN` as the first argument, it would still work just fine, but so as to not confuse anyone I've changed it to `undefined`.

Comment: @adeneo Seems you and T.J.Crowder sorted it out!

Comment: @Arbel - we always do, basically I do what he tells me to do!